# PHP TwitterOAuth account/verify_credentials returning 401

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I'm using abraham's twitter oauth class (https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) to connect and update twitter. I had it working during testing but now I'm trying to put it onto my live server I'm getting a 401 Could Not Authenticate error.

The original connection works ok (200 response) but when I use `$connection->get('account/verify_credentials');` it just 401's and says it cannot authenticate.

From looking at the $connection object, the [consumer] callback_url property is blank. Could this be the problem?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I didnt need to be running this unless I've already authenticated once through twitter, for some reason I was trying to run this directly after connecting, obviously there were no auth tokens so it wouldn't authenticate.

Silly me.

Comment: Glad you hear you got it figured out.